# Adding login items from terminal in Catalina

Tags: terminal, applescript, catalina, login-items

I've tried multiple ways but none work.
A few AppleScripts and even some bash script somebody made. Which essentially just executes a different AppleScript afaik.

**Some of the commands I have tried:**

```
osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to make new login item at end with properties {path:"/Applications/AppName.app", name:"App Name", hidden:true}'

defaults write ~/Library/Preferences/loginwindow AutoLaunchedApplicationDictionary -array-add '{Path="/Applications/AppName.app";}'

defaults write loginwindow AutoLaunchedApplicationDictionary -array-add '{ "Name" = "AppName" ; "Path" = "/Applications/AppName.app"; "Hide" = 0; }'

defaults write loginwindow AutoLaunchedApplicationDictionary -array-add '<dict><key>Hide</key><false/><key>Path</key><string>/path/to/item</string></dict>'
```

Comment: Posting a few samples of the AppleScript and bash script code which *doesn't* work can help determine what may be wrong.

Comment: Done. Edited the post.

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling AEServer and/or Script Editor in System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Accessibility. Occasionally I've had to quit and relaunch System Preferences for new login items added via AppleScript to appear.

After doing this I was able to add login items via AppleScript. Confusingly, after I disabled Accessibility access for AEServer and Script Editor I was still able to add login items via AppleScript.

Comment: I just tested this in **macOS Catalina 10.15.4** and it does not work!

Comment: Sorry to hear that   I'm also on 10.15.4 and it worked for me. Did you try restarting System Preferences? Also, from which app are you running the script?

Comment: Yes I restarted System Preferences. Tried in both Script Editor and Terminal, both have permission as well as AEServer.

Comment: A wild stab in the dark: Did you grant them permission in an earlier version of MacOS? If so, try disabling and re-enabling. Other than that, I would restart your computer and hope for the best. Sorry I can't be more helpful.

Comment: This is on a clean built system running **macOS Catalina 10.15.4** and also has been rebooted before and after adding **AEServer** and it didn't work.